# How can I upload images with ftp in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, ftp

I tried to upload images to ftp server, but I can't connect to it.

a.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="b.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
            <input value="upload" name="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and b.php:

```
<?php
$host = 'ftp.uw.hu';
$usr = 'myname';
$pwd = 'mypass';
$local_file = $_FILES['file'];
$ftp_path = '/a/'.$_FILES['file'].'(2)';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);
?>
```

I always get "Cannot connect to host" error message, but I don't know why.
I tried another ftp server (ftp.atw.hu) but I got the same error.

Comment: Check the `ftp_connect()` is in disabled function list in php.ini or `if(function_exists('ftp_connect') ) { echo "ftp_connect() fn exists"; } else echo 'not';`

Comment: I got "ftp_connect() fn exists" message.

Comment: The error is "Cannot connect to host". So check the host and is port number.

Comment: With Total Commander I can connect to it, and I checked the forbidden commands list and not contains ftp commands. I already tried ftp_connect($host, 21) too, but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php
This may help you!!! Refer it!!!